# CSS sprites for maximum accessibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, css-sprites

Suppose I want to replace a link `>` with a fancy image arrow. For that I want to use a CSS sprite.

In many articles, for example in a *recent* (2012) article in [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/11/css-sprites-revisited/), the recommended method is something like this:

- HTML:

  ```
  <a href="/article/123" class="nextLink">&gt;</a>
  ```
- CSS: hide text and specify sprite as background

However this method is problematic concerning accessibility: If images are disabled but CSS is interpreted, then the above link will be invisible.

Interestingly, I found an *old* (2010) [article by Paciello Group](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/01/high-contrast-proof-css-sprites/) that proposes what looks like a good solution. The idea is to place a `<span>` next to the text to be replaced. The `<span>` has a background image and is positioned on top of the text. If the image loads, it replaces the text, otherwise the text is still visible.

Why is this method not widely employed? Are there issues with that solution?

Comment: There are a lot of different stylised arrow characters available if you're using a UTF8 character set. You can probably Google a list of available arrows you could use, maybe one of those is the sort of thing you could use? ↝↣↠↬↯↱↳↺⇉⇄⇒⇗⇛⇢⇝➔➝➜➢➠➥➬➳➲➼ ( a bit hard to see in small font sizes, but you could copy/paste into a text editor to see)

Comment: The arrow was just an example. Something else could be a link to Twitter where the text "Twitter" is replaced by the bird icon. Granted in the case of a link to Twitter, the text would be cropped by CSS, but at least users would see that there is something.

Comment: You can make 'font icons' which *should* be rendered in these cases (as they are part of the text at this point). http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ is a pretty good place to get your feet wet on the concept.

Comment: Fonts have the limitation of being monochrome.

Comment: Icons have the limitation of not being visible to blind people, so using only iconography has limitations too. I'd say there are as many people who are browsing blind as browse with high contrast turned on (using that article you linked to as an example)

Comment: @AshleySheridan, accessibility is why I'm asking. Doesn't the Paciello Group's proposal work well for blind people?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main disadvantage is showing the text to users with no special accessibility needs, before your CSS sprite loads. In terms of code, it is also perhaps not as semantically clean as using an `aria-label` solution (explained below).

You could consider using an ARIA label for the element:

> The `aria-label` attribute is used to define a string that labels the current element. Use it in cases where a text label is not visible on the screen.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

I quickly checked how Gmail and Facebook approach this problem (buttons without text):

- In Gmail the 'previous' button has an aria-label of 'Older'
- in Facebook the 'cog' icon in top right has some text 'Account Settings' indented -5000em

Comment: Text is cropped in this case, naturally. Still cropped text (plus perhaps a title property and a border) is better than nothing. It acts as a placeholder to show users that there is something.

Comment: `aria-label` looks interesting - thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: No problem. Just had a very quick look at how Gmail and Faceook approach this problem (buttons without text). In Gmail the 'previous' button has an aria-label of 'Older', in Facebook the 'cog' icon in top right has some text 'Account Settings' indented -5000em

Comment: Could you please update your answer to make it more appropriate to my question? I suggest removing that the text has to be smaller (it would be cropped, naturally), and removing the indent solution (that's just one possibility to *hide* and already mentioned in the Smashing Magazine article). Furthermore, please add your findings about Gmail and Facebook - they are interesting!

Comment: You may mention, though that cropping is necessary but may lead to unreadable text. I am just looking forward to seeing a great answer for the benefit of all!

Comment: hope that edit covered it all? sorry just getting to grips with stackoverflow!

Comment: Great, and indeed very helpful!